# Ocultar código html5, php de una web

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5, css

¿Existe algún método para ocultar mis líneas de código al realizar la inspección mediante el navegador?

Comment: Hola DigitalHacks, bienvenid@. Procura hacer preguntas menos abiertas. Si alguien te contestara a la pregunta podría decirte: "si, existe" pero eso no te resolveria nada. Además puede haber muchos metodos distintosy seria muy amplia la respuesta. Te recomiendo que busques un poco por google y con lo que saques en claro, preguntar sobre una duda en concreto o los fallos que tienes al implementarlo. Un saludo

Comment: No. Puedes intentar ofuscar el código para que resulte difícil de leer. Pero no imposible. Además, de la misma manera que se puede aplicar la ofuscación, hay aplicaciones que retornan el código a una forma de legibilidad adecuada. Recuerda siempre, si el usuario descarga el código, tiene acceso al código. Otra opción es usar web components y `shadow DOM`, pero igualmente, no ocultas el código por completo, solo lo pones un poco más difícil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta más sencilla es no.

Puedes ponerlo más difícil, como por ejemplo deshabilitando algunos eventos que abran el inspector (como deshabilitar el clic derecho > inspeccionar o el F12), pero siempre existirá alguna manera para ver el código fuente de la página que le llega al cliente.

Puedes echar un vistazo a algunos trucos propuestos por la comunidad en inglés aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319786/how-to-hide-form-code-from-view-code-inspect-element-browser

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Antes de responder una pregunta como esta puedes guiarte por los comentarios que tenga. Si te fijas se le está pidiendo que cambie su pregunta por ser demasiado amplia. Lo normal es que en este estado se cierre. Por lo tanto es mejor no responder hasta que la pregunta cumpla con los requisitos del sitio para evitar conjeturas.